# Visual Studio не может прочитать h-файлы

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, build-error

Установил VS 2022. Не проходит сборку. Почти все ошибки говорят что "невозможно прочитать файл <название заголовочного файла>"
Конечно можно указать путь к mingw, но делать это для всех проектов индивидуально не хочется, а как это сделать для всех проектов сразу и на будущее (по умолчанию) не знаю.
Вопрос в том откуда столько ошибок и как это исправить(навсегда!).
Пробовал переустанавливать, ставить через консоль, т.е. через layout, не помогло ничего.

А всё из-за задания в универе написать функцию на плюсах

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> //включает в себя math.h из методички
using namespace std;
int main()
    {
        double x = 3.251, y = 0.325, z = 0.446 * pow(10, -4), s;
        int i;
        s = pow(2, pow(y, x)) + pow(pow(3, x), y) - (y * (atan(z-1/(double)3))) /
                                            (double)(abs(x) + 1/(double)pow(y, 2) + 1);
    
        cout << s << endl;
    
        // to hold console open
        cin >> i;
    
    }
```

P.S. если компилировать вручную с g++, то консоль быстро закрывалась. Для getch() нужно было бы подключать ещё что-то (conio.h по-моему), поэтому оставите на таких костылях (препод потом обо***л костыль и поставил 7 баллов -_-)

Настройки проекта для user7860670
[image: General]
[image: VC++ Directories]

Comment: Приводите настройки проекта, прежде всего General и VC++ Directories.

Comment: Добавил. Повторюсь, что ошибки возникали на свежем VC с модулем для разработки приложений на C++, ну то есть установил - открыл проект - ошибки)

Comment: Для `Включаемые каталоги` обычное значение `$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);`. При редактировании значения справа будет стрелочка для выпадающего списка, где будет пункт для сброса этого поля на значение по-умочанию. А если выбрать там пункт для редактирования, то можно будет открыть редактор, в котором будет показано, во что разворачивается это значение. И там по идее будет целая пачка папок типа "...10.0.20348.0\ucrt", одной этой папки недостаточно.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Помог гайд азиатского друга, посмотреть его можно [здесь](https://jingyan.baidu.com/album/8ebacdf0167b2249f65cd5eb.html?picindex=1).

Заходим в проект и жмакаем:

> Проект >> Свойства <имя проекта> >> Каталоги VC++.
> Добавляем во Включаемые каталоги путь к Windows SDK (как ни странно), по умолчанию путь:
> C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt

*Где "10.0.20348.0" - версия установленного SDK

Comment: Ничего подобного делать нет необходимости, так как в создаваемых проектах все нужные директории включаются по-умолчанию.

Comment: да, включаются, но почему-то VS при сборке НЕ МОЖЕТ ИХ ПРОЧЕСТЬ!!! из-за чего при включении iostream появляется УЖЕ 400+ ошибок